# find xpath for 'PAINEL DE CONTROLE EDITORA'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath

[image]

Facing issues while locating element outside the span please refer the images and post the xpath for it.

Update:

I have tried the suggestion in Upkar Singh's answer and the xpath below with no success. After `<span></span>` nothing is accessible.

```
.//*[contains(text(),'PAINEL DE CONTROLE EDITORA')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a situation where dot works and text() does not.  I don't understand dot enough to know why at this point, but the answers on this question go into detail about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text/38240971

```
//span[contains(., 'PAINEL DE CONTROLE EDITORA')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this work for you-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@class='title'][contains(text(),'PAINEL DE CONTROLE EDITORA')]"));
```

Comment: this xpath is not working

Comment: add your stacktrace to your question.

Comment: Even .//*[contains(text(),'PAINEL DE CONTROLE EDITORA')] is not working

Comment: I understand some times it does not work, what is in your stacktrace can you please tell?

Comment: If this is not working then try to make Xpath from root element that will easily work.

Comment: Even from root element it is not detecting... after <span></span> nothing is accessible.

Comment: Nothing is inside the ```<span></span>```element so what you want to access inside this element.

Comment: I was just informing you that after this tag <span></span> I am not able to access the text written. I am not able to locate that text even from simple methods of contains also.

Comment: what is in your console can you share ?